# C# Seqpacket

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I've done some research, and there is very little (basically none) information on how to create a socket of type SeqPacket in C#
doing this will fail:
listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Seqpacket, ProtocolType.Tcp);
I'm new to networking, so I'm probably doing something really stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SocketType.Seqpacket is only supported in NetBIOS.  There is no reason to use this with TCP connections.

See this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/5f15fb4a-e691-4805-bc61-53c3e6ffc55b) for details.

Comment: Sounds like it falls quite solidly under the "doing something stupid" heading then ;)
I want a packet based connection rather than a stream based one. So I assume I should use rdm instead? or should I just use a stream and figure out some way of simulating packets (prefix the length, delimiting sequence etc)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to networking, then I suggest that you stay away from low level stuff like sockets, unless this is homework. Use WCF instead.

Comment: I just sat down and decided I'd teach myself how to use sockets properly, I've messed with them a bit before but never properly. I may have a look at wcf anyway because I've never even heard of that.

Comment: "WCF" == "Windows Communications Framework". Does web services, and everything else, including named pipes, so maybe you'd get your seqpacket back.

Comment: Just been having a quick look on google, looks promising. Still going to fiddle with sockets first though ;)